# How to backup SVN repository from a server to linux machine using linux commands

Tags: svn, backup, remote-backup

I was trying to take the backup of svn from my linux server to local linux machine.

I am able to take the backup in server using svnadmin dump.

What should i do if I have to make the destination as one of the folder in my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the backup on the server (in a temporary location) and (s)cp it over to your local machine.